# How to not use cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I have a Dynamic Table on my project, on each cell I have a label that below under that label I want to apply a VisualEffectView effect, as for now I'm using cellForRowAtIndexPath, but I understand that its event repeats every time that the cell its focused on the table.

I want to calculate how many items I have on my table, there always gonna be that label, which under it I will be applying the effect. I was trying something like this on my viewDidLoad method:

```
for (UILabel *v in self.myCell) {

    [v setText:@"Holaaa"];
}
```

I did this just to try.

Any advice.

Comment: Also, doing it like that makes my table really slow as its creating the effect repeatedly

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not called every time a cell is focused. It's called each time the table needs to display a cell.

Comment: Well, on my custom cell on the awakeFromNib method I did the effect and its working perfectly fine. I'm doing it right?

Comment: Do not try to get around using cellForRowAtIndexPath -- you'll end up getting bit one way or the other.  Instead, work on making your "data source" contain all the necessary info so that cellForRowAtIndexPath does the minimum amount of work -- only customizing the views and not actually calculating anything.

Comment: Ok, but how to use this code on cellForRowAtIndexPath then? it gets to slow!

    `UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
    blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
    
    UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
    visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
    visualEffectView.layer.cornerRadius = visualEffectView.frame.size.width / 2;
    visualEffectView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    visualEffectView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    visualEffectView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    visualEffectView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;`

Comment: So, is every cell that way?  If so then the recycled cells will already be set up and you don't need to do that for recycled cells.  If certain parms need to be customized, you only need to customize the parms, not redo everything.  If not all cells are like that then you make use of "reuseIdentifier" to specify which is which when recycling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tableView will create a few cells, which will then be reused as the user is scrolling.

Therefore, cellForRowAtIndexPath will be called **many** times as the user scroll. Now I'm not really familiar with UIVisualEffect, but if you use this code in cellForRow, I assume it will add this visual effect view **every time** a cell is reused, thus making it slow.

The reason it's not slow in awakeFromNib is because you only add it **once** to the cell. I would say awakeFromNib or init is a better place to add is this view, since you only want to add it once, and not each time a cell is reused.